# UnityException: Unable to find suitable JDK installation

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, java-10

I have a simple Unity project that I want to export for Android. I installed the latest version of Java SE (JDK 10) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), but Unity keeps saying that it can't find a suitable JDK installation and that it needs JDK 8 or later (which I have).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that Unity doesn't seem to support JDK 10 yet. Installing JDK 8 fixed it.

I also had to add the bin folder's location to the `Path` variable in my system variables.